# How to make it so not every sound plays at once when hovering over a card

Tags: javascript, html

I tried making character cards, that when hovered over play the character his / her voiceline (only relevant parts shown), but when I hover over a character, they play every voiceline all at once, it's probably a mistake in the javascript, but I just can't figure out how to fix it.

```
          <ul>
            <header id="play_1">
                <img src="/img/characters/character.png">
              <audio>
                <source src="/voices/charactervoice.m4a"></source>
              </audio>
            </header>
          </ul>
          
          <ul>
            <header id="play_2>
                <img src="/img/characters/character2.png">
              <audio>
                <source src="/voices/charactervoice2.m4a"></source>
              </audio>
            </header>
          </ul>





//javascript:

window.onload=function(){

for (let i = 1; i <= 2; i++){
    var playHover = document.getElementById('play_' + i),
    audios = document.querySelectorAll('audio');
console.log(audios);


playHover.addEventListener('mouseover', function() {
[].forEach.call(audios, function(audio) {
    audio.volume = 0.05;
  audio.play();
});
}, false);
}
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It should only select the audio inside the `playHover` and not all the audio which is causing all the audio to play at once when hovering a card. You can try it like this (basing on how you written your code)

```
window.onload=function(){
    for (let i = 1; i <= 2; i++){
         let playHover = document.querySelector('#play_' + i),
         let audio = playHover.querySelector('audio');

         playHover.addEventListener('mouseover', function() {
             audio.volume = 0.05;
             audio.play();
         }, false);
    }
}
```

or you can code it like this so whenever you're going to add a header you won't have to edit your loop condition. (Ideally, you should place a class for each header and select that instead so if ever you are going to use the header element for another use, won't have problems with selections):

```
window.onload=function(){
    const headers = document.querySelectorAll('header');

    headers.forEach((e) => {
        let audio = e.querySelector('audio');

        e.addEventListener('mouseover', function() {
             audio.volume = 0.05;
             audio.play();
        }, false);
    });
}
```